# Migrations. How to describe current database schema?

Tags: php, migration, yii

Question about migrations, announced at one of the latest releases(1.1.6, am I right?)

So, i have a site working with yii 1.1.5 and i want use migrations now, cause site progressing every day. What is the best way to describe first migration, which include all my current database schema?

Comment: If you're on mysql, you can use mysqldump to export the DDL for your database, which can go into source control.

Comment: >1.1.6, am I right? <- no, current Version is 1.1.7

Comment: This is done by one line from shell. Look for mysqldump [in this article](http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-backup-and-restore-export-and-import-mysql-databases-tutorial/).

Answer (score 0):

when you say describe first migration do you mean the class and file name?

```
yiic migrate create init_db_schema
```

EDIT
In which case I don't believe the migration tool can reverse engineer an existing db and create the migration for you. So, you'll probably have to manually do it. You could use PHPMyAdmin, MySQL Browser/Workbench to generate the CREATE commands for you and inside your migration script, create the command e.g.

```
$cmd = $this->getDbConnection()->createCommand($sql);
$cmd->execute();
```

Comment: I mean, that i already have very big database structure, that was made with yii framework, when it was without migration's features. With earlier releases. And now i just want generate all that database structure(schema) for migration file, which you named init_db_schema. So, where the easiest way for this? I don't wanna make this manually.